# Teradata Case Expression and Text Comparison <> Not Working

Tags: case, teradata

I am trying to run a Case expression that will return a value when a field does not equal a specific text value.

Specifically, I am trying to return 'YES' when the field does not equal 'Yes'.  The current value is null.  I would expect the result to return 'YES' since the value does not equal 'Yes'.  The query is returning 'NO'.

The excerpt of my query is listed below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT  
        CASE 
            WHEN "Renewal"<>'Yes'
            THEN 'YES' 
            ELSE 'NO' 
        END
FROM    "DATABASE"."TABLE"
WHERE     "Asset_Id" = '006817'
```

Comment: Equals and not equals do not work with null values. Typically you would catch it with an else block.  But in your case you need when `when renewal is null then 'YES'`.

Comment: If I were looking for a null value, I would agree with this.  There are several other potential text values that can be in this field.  I want to pull everything that is not a 'Yes' response including a Null value.

Comment: I'm not telling you to drop the `<> 'yes' ` test, you just need to also include the `is null` test.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Alternatively: `CASE WHEN COALESCE(Renewal, 'NotYes') <>'Yes' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END`

Comment: This works well too.  Thank you!